Why do I get an excess element warning in this tagged union in gcc C?
I am writing a tagged union in C, the definition is as follows:
struct uuid_0000000000061d0c {
   long _0;
   union {
      struct {void* _1;};  
      struct {char* _1001; char* _1002;};       
      struct {char* _2001;};
      struct {};
   };
};

There are four anonymous cases in a tagged union. My question is when I initialize this with the "large" two field case I end up with a warning "warning: excess elements in struct initializer".
struct uuid_0000000000061d0c an_instance = { 1, "a", "b" }; 

Following my intuition I successfully restructured the original type definition to avoid the error. Basically, moving the anonymous struct with the largest number of fields to the start of the union fixes this warning.
struct uuid_0000000000061d0c {
   long _0;
   union {
      struct {char* _1001; char* _1002;}; 
      struct {void* _1;};
      struct {char* _2001;};
      struct {};
   };
};

Is this a bug with the warning or am I misunderstanding the intent of the warning?

The braces (without designated initializer) only ever initialize the first union member. How would the compiler be able to decide which of the union members you mean?

This doesn't seem to be the case as there is some amount of "intelligent" packing of unions. It seems that any case will unify with the type checker. Then codegen just dumps everything into the struct with some default alignment. I was wondering specifically just how much of this is intentional on the part of the compiler and how much is just coincidental.

@Andrew Johnson, why anonymous struct?  How do you want to access them?

The members are only ever accessed by fields which are given names. The union is guarded by the tag "_0" field, then the union is destructured only for the corresponding case.

@AndrewJohnson I don't know what you mean with ""intelligent" packing of unions", but there is nothing intelligent going on. The elements are initialized in order: 1 initializes _0, "a" initializes _1 and then there is nothing left for "b" to initialize, which results in the code being ill-formed. GCC seems to accept it as an extension anyway, by just ignoring the excess initializer with a warning. There is no type checking or unification or anything that is relevant to this.

Also as a side note: In standard C a struct can't be empty either. That is also a GCC extension.

"... moving the anonymous struct with the largest number of fields to the start of the union fixes this warning." --> more like moving the one that matched the initialization to the first fixed this issue.

Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers says: — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces. See also What does double underscore (__const) mean in C?

There are 3 non-conformance issues here:

struct {}; is invalid C syntax. Structs must have members.

struct uuid_0000000000061d0c an_instance = { 1, "a", "b" }; attempts to initialize 3 items in a struct which only has 2 items. GNU non-standard extensions can in some situations let through code with more initializers than elements, but that doesn't make the code valid C.
If you wish to initialize a particular union member the best way is to use designated initializers. If you don't use them, the first union member will get initialized. Why the fix "worked". Instead you should write something like:
{ ._0 = 1, ._1001 = "a", ._1002 = "b" };

Structs are usually declared at file scope so that multiple functions can access them. If that's what you are planning to do here, the members (or tag names) cannot start with _ since that's reserved for the compiler at file scope.



Apart from that, variable/type names exist solely for the benefit of the programmer, not to be confused with the data they contain. So please don't give types names such as uuid_0000000000061d0c the whole 0000000000061d0c thing is some sort of data and doesn't belong in a name. If this is from some auto-generated code, then that tool is not doing you any favours.

This is intermediate code so the C code is an artifact, but point taken. Thanks for highlighting where gcc diverges from standards.

As initialization did not specify which union member to use, it attempted to use the first one.
union { struct {void* _1;}; only needs one initializer.


The members are only ever accessed by fields which are given names.

Not in OP's case of initialization. It used the first ones.
Try initializing by name to only ever accessed by fields which are given names.
struct uuid_0000000000061d0c an_instance = 
    {  ._1001 = "a", ._1002 = "b", ._0 = 1 };

